# How to change the brightness of screen on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've move my system (ubuntu 16.04) from a computer with intel cpu to a computer with amd cpu. I've found that there is no single file or directory under `/sys/class/backlight/`, so `echo 30 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` is not working(but this command worked well in a computer with intel cpu). When I try to create a folder under `/sys/class/backlight/` with root permission, I got an error `Operation not permitted`. I've also tried `xbacklight`, it does not work as well. How can I change the brightness of screen in such situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this just puts a dark shade over your screen, but here it is.
First, put `xrandr -q` into your console. you will see a lot of stuff. In the front of all that stuff you'll see something like `maximum 50082 x 50082`. after that you will see something like `ePDi2`. remember that number. Put in `xrandr --output ePDi2 --brightness 0.7` into your console. Except instead of ePDi2, put in yours. 0.7 is 70% less than your actual brightness. 1.0 sets it back to normal. Don't do anything higher than 1.0 on your number, otherwise your screen will become white and you won't be able to see anything.

Comment: Great answer, just a note - was able to set brightness to 1.5 and it just got brighter and higher contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Type the command `ls /sys/class/backlight/`.
This will list the driver(s) controlling the backlight.

You might have to resort to writing a `.conf` file [similar to this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 desktop(GUI). I noticed that a lot of answers suggesting the way you described, but I don't have such directory either. So I simply change my brightness from `System Settings -> Power`, there is a bar you can move left and right to ajust the birgtness immediately. BTW, Fn+F9 or Fn+F10 does not work for me.